# Supertest double callback while iterating over array

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to get a version of the [Bowling Game kata](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata) running using Node and Express, and I'm seeing a peculiar issue. I could use some help understanding why from someone who knows Node and Express better than I do.

After writing the strike test case while trying to get the strike test case working, when I try to run the below tests using **mocha** at the command line, I get the following supertest error: `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at /Users/cdurfee/bitbucket/neontapir/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:125:21`.

However, if I comment out this seemingly innocuous line in game.js (`total += rolls[ball + 2];`), there are no failures, but of course the behavior is wrong. I suspect it's an array out of bounds issue, but I don't know a good way to figure that out.

Here's the full contents of both files and the console output of mocha.

```
08:55 $ mocha --reporter spec

  Scoring a bowling game
    gutter game
      ✓ should return 0 
    single pin game
      ✓ should return 20 
    spare
      ✓ should return 16 after spare and a 3 
    strike
      ✓ should return 24 after strike, 4 and a 3 
      1) should return 24 after strike, 4 and a 3
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
double callback!
    perfect game

  4 passing (71ms)
  1 failing

  1) Scoring a bowling game strike should return 24 after strike, 4 and a 3:
     Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at /Users/cdurfee/bitbucket/neontapir/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:125:21
      at Test.Request.callback (/Users/cdurfee/bitbucket/neontapir/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:660:30)
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/cdurfee/bitbucket/neontapir/node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:628:10)
      at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
      at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at net.js:441:14
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

**game.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = exports.app = express();

app.get('/start', function(req, res) {
    rolls = new Array();
    attempt = 0;
});

app.post('/bowl/:pins', function(req, res) {
    rolls[attempt] = parseInt(req.params.pins);
    attempt++;
});

app.get('/score', function(req, res) {
    var total = 0;
    var ball = 0;
    for (var frame = 0; frame < 10; frame++) {
        if (rolls[ball] + rolls[ball + 1] == 10) { 
            total += rolls[ball + 2]; // this line causes the double callback
        }
        total += rolls[ball] + rolls[ball + 1];
        ball += 2;
    }

    res.send(200, {score: total});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

**test/test.js**

```
var request = require('supertest'),
    should = require('should');
var game = require('../game.js').app;

var assertScoreEquals = function(expectedScore) {   
    request(game).get('/score').expect(200).end(function(err,res) {
      should.not.exist(err);        
      result = res.body;        
      result.should.have.property('score').eql(expectedScore);      
    });  
};

var roll = function(pins) {
    request(game).post('/bowl/' + pins).end();
};

var rollMany = function(times, pins) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        roll(pins);
    }
};

describe('Scoring a bowling game', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    request(game).get('/start').end();
  });

  describe('gutter game', function() {
        it('should return 0', function() {
            rollMany(20,0);
            assertScoreEquals(0);                       
        });
    });

    describe('single pin game', function() {
        it('should return 20', function() {
            rollMany(20,1);
            assertScoreEquals(20);          
        });
    });

    describe('spare', function() {
        it('should return 16 after spare and a 3', function() {         
            roll(6);
            roll(4); // spare
            roll(3);
            rollMany(17,0);
            assertScoreEquals(16);          
        });
    });

    // not expected to pass at the moment
    describe('strike', function() {
        it('should return 24 after strike, 4 and a 3', function() {         
            roll(10); // strike
            roll(4);
            roll(3);
            rollMany(17,0);
            assertScoreEquals(24);          
        });
    });

    // not expected to pass at the moment
    describe('perfect game', function() {
        it('should return 300', function() {    
            rollMany(12,10);
            assertScoreEquals(300);         
        });
    });         
});
```

Comment: One main issue I can see is that you're assuming things will execute synchronously.  You're sending the requests, but not waiting for each one to finish before sending the next. 
Also your server code is assuming that the bowls arrive in bowl order, which is never a given on internet.  I would suggest sending the bowl order as part of the request to /bowl, in case the bowl requests arrive out of order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding to my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615897/supertest-double-callback-while-iterating-over-array/25150012#comment39129400_22615897)

I also see that your test cases are not asynchronous, this is almost certainly your problem.

You should have a callback: `done`

```
  describe('gutter game', function() {
    it('should return 0', function(done) { // callback is provided as argument by mocha 
        rollMany(20,0);
        assertScoreEquals(0);
        done();  // This needs to be called when the test is finished, for async operations.
    });
});
```

I would suggest perhaps using [supertest-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supertest-as-promised) instead of supertest, as this can make things easier when you need to run a lot of requests.  This library, plus perhaps [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) can make tests like yours simpler.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/lingo/d972e618b4f226866be2) has my rewrite of your tests, using `Bluebird` promises and `supertest-as-promised`, with comments on what I've changed.

Comment: Luke, you are a scholar and a gentleman! I'm ecstatic about the amount of effort you took not only to reply but to illustrate how to use supertest-as-promised and Bluebird! Thanks again!

Comment: Heh, you're welcome.  I'm still improving my node-skills myself, so I'm glad to help point out the traps I've recently stepped in!  By the way, I've slightly updated the gist with a couple of things that I thought were missing.

Comment: Latest changes to gist: https://gist.github.com/lingo/d972e618b4f226866be2/revisions